# Symfony2.3 Form Test Error - options do not exists

Tags: phpunit, symfony-2.3

I am doing Form Testing in Symfony2.3 project and I got the error that there are no options. 
 I don't understand why this happens.

```
AdminMessageBundle\Tests\Form\ServiceAlertTypeTest::testSubmitValidData 
with data set #0 
(array(1, 'magic', '#2A8BCC', 'www', '23/12/14', 'text', 'all'))

Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidOptionsException: 
The options "attr", "class", "label", "multiple", "property", "query_builder",
"required" do not exist. 
Known options are: ""
```

Here is my Form Builder

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use MessageBundle\Utility\AlertForm;

/**
 * Class ServiceAlertType
 * @package Acme\MessageBundle\Form
 */
class ServiceAlertType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

    if (!isset($options['attr']['date_format_js'])) {
        $options['attr']['date_format'] = 'd/m/Y';
    }
    if (!isset($options['attr']['date_format_js'])) {
        $options['attr']['date_format_js'] = 'd/m/yyyy';
    }

    if (!isset($options['attr']['scope'])) {
        $options['attr']['scope'] = 'Empty Scope Error';
    }

    $builder
        ->add('icon', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => AlertForm::getIcons(),
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'icon-select'
            ),
        ))
        ->add('color', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => AlertForm::getColors(true),
            'label' => 'Choice color',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'hidden'
            )
        ))
        ->add('text', 'textarea', array(
            'required' => true
        ))
        ->add('link', 'url', array(
            'required' => true
        ))
        ->add('date', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'date-picker',
                'data-date-format' => $options['attr']['date_format_js'],
                'value' => date($options['attr']['date_format']),
                'input_group' => array(
                    'prepend' => '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>',
                    'size' => 'small'
                ),
                'widget_col'  => 2,
            )
        ))
        ->add('all_users', 'checkbox', array(
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add(
            'scope',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
                },
                'property' => 'username',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Users',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'chzn-select',
                )
            )
        )
    ;

    $error = $options['attr']['scope'];

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function ($event) use ($error) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        if (empty($data['all_users']) && !count($data['scope'])) {
            $form->get('scope')->addError(new FormError($error));
            return;
        }
    });

    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
    return 'editorial_alert';
    }
}
```

And here is my Test Class

```
use MessageBundle\Entity\ServiceAlert;
use MessageBundle\Form\ServiceAlertType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\PreloadedExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;

class ServiceAlertTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

    protected function setUp()
    {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ->addExtensions($this->getExtensions())
        ->getFormFactory();
    }

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
    $mockEntityType = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mockEntityType->expects($this->any())->method('getName')
        ->will($this->returnValue('entity'));

    return array(new PreloadedExtension(array(
        $mockEntityType->getName() => $mockEntityType,
    ), array()));
    }


    public function getValidFormData()
    {

    $data = array(
        array(
            'data' => array(
                'id'=> 1,
                'icon' => 'magic',
                'color' => '#2A8BCC',
                'link' => 'www.example.com',
                'date' => '23/12/14',
                'text' => 'text',
                'all_users' => 'all'

            )
        )
    );

    return $data;
    }


    /**
     * @dataProvider getValidFormData
     */
    public function testSubmitValidData($data)
    {

    $type = new ServiceAlertType(new TestChildType());
    $form = $this->factory->create($type);

    // submit the data to the form directly
    $form->submit($data);

    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());


    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `setDefaultOptions` method in your Form class